# Is Sherlock Holmes good to study English?

Tags: reading, reading-comprehension

The novel was first published over 100 years ago. Its English might be quite different than it is now. The question is this: Will reading it help me to improve my English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons the Sherlock Holmes books were so popular in their time and still are all over the world is that Doyle ensured to write them for a larger audience, meaning that the language is simplified so more readers could understand it.

To this day, Sherlock Holmes is still one of the most popular fictional characters and the books about his adventures written by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle (1859-1930) are in the lists of must-reads for English language learners aiming both to enhance their vocabulary and improve their command of the English language.